# ERC20 tokens taken from MyEtherwallet

Tags: wallets, tokens, security, erc-20, myetherwallet

99% of my ERC20 tokens have all been taken out of Exodus

Please someone help me!

After one day of registering with myetherwallet my tokens went missing...

I bought 10 differnt ERC20 tokens in etherDelta and withdrew them to MyEtherWallet.com. I double checked my wallet at that time and everything was fine - all tokens showed.

The next morning (13 hours later) I looked in 'MyEtherWallet.com" and they were gone. I thin went to Exodus and my etherium was gone from there also.

I can see 10 of my tokens in some one elses wallet. There are 3 others in there that arent mine.

They havent been moved or sold in the past 5 days, which if taken on purpose I believe they would have been by now

A few things sorted:
1. The myetherwallet.com webpage wasn't a fake one - so I can rule that out. I was aware of this before going into page of hoax ones.

2. I didnt recieve any hoax emails between buying them and transfering them to myehterwallet.

When pulling over the tokens I didnt have etherium my account - is this a concern??

Could there be a place where tokens are held if no etherium in my account. I have now placed Etherium in my account..still no coins back.

Im running on MAC OS. Sierra

myetherwallet address: 0x31ED4777B2EDBd3a4F859Bf91f34C6C2324FCd35

You can view the tokens at https://etherscan.io/address/0x85b9d9cd19441642b730a94f4c496eb909828dd8#tokentxns

Only the DataCoin and INS Promo are not mine - everything else is mine.

Please, can anyone give me advice in what I can do to get them back.

Comment: Please go through your browser history and double check any recent visits to etherdelta, MyEtherWallet, exchanges, and more. Please also double-check any applications you have downloaded, airdrops you entered your private key on, or anything else

Comment: thanks Tayvanno..do you think someone grabbed my private key somehow while I was asleep. 12 hours after I bought them...starnge that they sit in the persons account with 4 other cryptos that arent mine...they sit there as if the person doesnt know they are there...they ahvent moved for the past 2 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

There are no such things as etherscan's, myetherwallet's or etherdelta's addresses, these sites merely allow you to read and interact with the ethereum blockchain where your address is registered.

So is "0x85b9d9cd19441642b730a94f4c496eb909828dd8" your address and does it display the correct balances on the link your provided?https://etherscan.io/address/0x85b9d9cd19441642b730a94f4c496eb909828dd8

Comment: Thanks Oliver for replying. Im new to crptocurrencies. Yes you are correct...this was linked to my Exodus address...the exodus address: 0x31ED4777B2EDBd3a4F859Bf91f34C6C2324FCd35   the address 0x85b9d9cd19441642b730a94f4c496eb909828dd8 is someone elses address which contains my tokens

Comment: So 0x31ED*** is your address, and indeed I can see a lots of transfers going from there to 0x85b9*** which does not belong to you. If you did not initiate these, someone else did - in any case neither you, nor etherscan can do anything if you dont have the private key. I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks Oliver...not good...But thats life sometimes I guess. Starnge that they just sit in the account and dont move.